# Where's boost::get_reference() now?

Tags: boost

Since boost::mutex is not "Default Constructible", I cannot get a reference of it directly. I googled this problem, and find get_reference() is probably the solution. But I find in my "boost/utility/" folder, there's no "get_reference.hpp".

Does anyone know whether get_reference() is still supported? Or any alternative solutions of this problem (get a reference of boost::mutex)?

Thanks, Cui

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to accomplish with a reference to a mutex? Where is `get_reference.hpp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::mutex` **is** default-constructible. It is not *copiable*. Your question is unclear, but I guess you're trying to use `mutex` in a `bind` expression or to pass `mutex` to an algorithm that copies its arguments, and you're looking for `boost::ref` wrapper, aren't you?

```
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
//...
boost::ref(yourMutex)
```

Comment: "pass mutex to an algorithm that copies its arguments", that's exactly what I want! Thank you!